# js inheritance cant use super class unction with base class object

Tags: javascript

i am tying to implement basic inheritance, bellow is my min reproducible code, I want to call eat function in dev1 but It says that dev1 does not have eat function. i tried writing all oof it in HTML script tag

```
//parent class
        function Person(name, location) {
            this.name = name
            this.location = location

        }
// parent class function
        Person.prototype.eat = function () {
            document.write("i like sea food ")
        }
        
//child class
        function Developer(name, location, projects) {
            Person.call(this, name, location)
            this.projects = projects
        }
        
// object
        var dev1 = new Developer("abc", "xyz", ["aa", "bb"])




        
        dev1.eat()
```

Comment: You're missing the actual inheritance of the prototype; `Person.call(..)` just applies the constructor code, it doesn't inherit the prototype. See the above linked duplicate.

Comment: okay got it thanks.